# React Native Android azure build failing randomly

Tags: android, azure, react-native, azure-notificationhub

Azure pipeline is trying to download a resource from 'https://dl.bintray.com/microsoftazuremobile/SDK/'.

The same thing had been working for a year so Gradle config doesn't seem an issue but for a week now it is failing randomly.

Actual error :

```
> Could not get resource 'https://dl.bintray.com/microsoftazuremobile/SDK/com/huawei/hms/update/2.0.6.302/update-2.0.6.302.pom'.
> Could not GET 'https://dl.bintray.com/microsoftazuremobile/SDK/com/huawei/hms/update/2.0.6.302/update-2.0.6.302.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
```

Any ideas how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the repo has been moved and docs are not updated.
Changed the repo from bintray to mavenCentral

```
-   maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/microsoftazuremobile/SDK' }
+   mavenCentral()
```

It works perfectly